# Illegal string offset en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo este error:

> ErrorException in PuntuacionesCtrl.php line 70:
>   Illegal string offset 'actividad_id'

y no sé como solucionarlo, este es mi código, la primera linea es la 70 donde me da el error:

```
    $actividad_id = $request->detalle['actividad_id'];
    $puntos = $request->detalle['puntos'];
    $cont= 0;
    while($cont < count($actividad_id)){
        $detalle = new Detalle();
        $detalle->puntuacion_id= $puntuacion->id;
        $detalle->actividad_id= $actividad_id[$cont];
        $detalle->puntos= $puntos[$cont];
        $detalle->save();

        $cont=$cont + 1;
    }
```

así lo tengo en el formulario:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" name="actividad_id" ng-model="puntuacion.detalle.actividad_id" ng-options="actividad.id as actividad.nombre for actividad in actividades | filter:{ circular_id: puntuacion.circular_id, tipo_a_id: 1} "></select>
```

hice:

```
 dump($request->detalle);
```

y me sale [object Object] aquí la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error dice que no está definida `actividad_id`, probablemente `$request->detalle` no sea un array. ¿Puedes agregar un dump de dicha variable?

Comment: hice var_dump($request->detalle); y me sale esto: string(15) "[object Object]"

Comment: haz `dump($request->detalle)` y edita la pregunta para agregar dicho resultado.

Comment: listo, esta bien así?

Comment: intenta con $request->detalle->actividad_id

Comment: yo intente con ese, y me sale Illegal string offset 'actividad_id'

Comment: a no, me lanza este error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: no se que pasaría, porq yo tenia eso bien así funcionando fino, y hoy lo probe y me salio con ese error ahora :(

Comment: llevoo todo el día viendo como lo soluciono pero nada :/ porfis ayuda!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65864/discussion-between-ziuling-macayo-and-shaz).

Comment: el error puede estar en que el angular no está enviando el array de detalle al request? @Shaz

Comment: Algo así creería yo, sin embargo no conozco mucho Angular entonces no puedo opinar al respecto.